# Python Formatter Black - how to modify format of retrieving a dict value

Tags: python, format

I just set up my VS Code to use Black, the python formatter. The default format puts a dict key on a new line when referencing a value, like this,

```
my_function_call(
    my_dict[
        "my_key"
    ],
    function_param2=var,
    function_param3=another_var
)
```

I never write keys on a new line like that when referencing a dictionary. Instead, I would rather set it up on the same line, like so,

```
my_function_call(
    function_param1=my_dict["my_key"],
    function_param2=var,
    function_param3=another_var
)
```

Is there a way to save specific modifications like this, or is black a take-what-you-get kind of extension? I haven't found anything in their docs or in a google search mentioning modifications
EDIT: Just checked and this is not due to black's default line length. The line of code I'm testing is not longer than default 88 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot configure how Black formats your code except for setting the line length. It intentionally doesn't have options to control formatting.

> Black is the uncompromising Python code formatter. By using it, you agree to **cede control over minutiae of hand-formatting**. – [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/black/)